# What term refers to the written characters used before kanji?

Tags: meaning, words

The kanji characters were borrowed from China, so what were the written language characters called before kanji was introduced?

Comment: Did we have a writing system before we borrowed Chinese characters..?

Comment: I was able to determine that kanji are considered to be a modern writing system, leading me to believe that something was in place prior.

Comment: Can you share the source? I'm curious to read more about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generally accepted view is that there was no pre-kanji written script in Japan.

There are occasional claims of the existance of pre-kanji scripts called [神代文字]{じんだいもじ}. As the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jindai_moji) page mentions:

> Some have claimed since the mid-Edo period that such ancient characters, for example such as Chikushi characters and Hokkaido characters, have been found in archeological remains, in Kofun and on mountains, but **all jindai moji are generally considered to be forgeries**.